# If $f$ is a meromorphic modular form of weight $k$, then $\frac{1}{f}$ is a modular form of weight $-k$

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

Since $f$ is a modular form of weight k, it satisfies $$f(M\tau)=(c\tau+d)^kf(\tau)$$, where $M\tau$ denotes the usual Mobius-transformation. Is the following approach right?

$$f(M\tau)=(c\tau+d)^kf(\tau) \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{f(M\tau)}=(c\tau+d)^{-k}\frac{1}{f(\tau)}$$

So $\frac{1}{f}$ would satisfy the equation and further would be meromorphic, since we can take the set of roots from f away from $\mathbb{H}$?

Which is open, too, is how to justify the fourier-expansion. Is it equivalent to 1/f having a root in $\infty$?

Comment: If $f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{H}$ and modular of weight $k$, then $1/f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{H}$ and modular of weight $-k$. Hence $\frac{1}{f(\tau+1)} = \frac{1}{f(\tau)}$ and it has a Fourier expansion $\sum_n a_n e^{2i \pi n \tau}$.

Comment: So the part that $1/f$ is modular of weight $-k$ follows right from my result? Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes of course, and taking $M = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ you have the $1$ periodicity, but the rest is unclear.

Comment: But is there anything left to show, now? We've shown that it is meromorphic and modular of weight $-k$. And It has a proper Fourier expansion which is equivalent that it has at most 1 pole at $\infty$. I think these are all of my requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function on $\mathbb{H} : Im(\tau) > 0$ is said modular of weight $k$ (for the full modular group $\Gamma \simeq SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$) iff for every $\gamma \in \Gamma$ : $\forall \tau \in \mathbb{H},\ f(\tau) =  f |_k\gamma(\tau) \overset{def}=f(\gamma \tau) (c\tau+d)^{-k} $.

It is said to be a meromorphic modular form iff it is meromorphic on $\mathbb{H}$ and also at the unique cusp $i\infty$ of $\mathbb{C} / \Gamma$, that is as $\tau \to i\infty$  : $f(\tau) \sim e^{2i \pi m \tau}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. When $m \ge 0$ we call it a modular form, and when $m > 0$ a cusp form.

As you noticed, for every $\gamma \in \Gamma$ : $\forall \tau \in \mathbb{H}, \frac{1}{f(\gamma \tau)} (c\tau+d)^{k} = \frac{1}{f(\tau)}$ that is $f$ modular of weight $k$ implies $1/f$ modular of weight $-k$.

Also, $f$ meromorphic on $\mathbb{H}$ means that $1/f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{H}$, so all we have to check is that $1/f$ is meromorphic at the cusp.

And for this, look at $g(q) = f(\frac{\log(q)}{2i \pi})$ that is a function defined for $0 < |q| < 1$. Note how $f(\tau+1) = f(\tau)$ and meromorphic on $\mathbb{H}$ means that $g(q)$ is well-defined and **meromorphic on $0 < |q| < 1$** (not depending on the branch of the logarithm you choose, see [this example plot of $g(q)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series#/media/File:Gee_three_real.jpeg) for $f$ an Eiseinstein series)

Now $f$ meromorphic at the cusp means that $g(q)q^m$ has a removable singularity at $q=0$, i.e. $g(q)$ is meromorphic around $q= 0$, and so is $\frac{1}{g(q)}$, thus it has a Laurent series
$$\frac{1}{g(q)} = \sum_{n = -m}^\infty c_n q^n$$
and since $\frac{1}{f(\tau)} = \frac{1}{g(e^{2i \pi \tau})}$ you have that $\frac{1}{f(\tau)} =  \sum_{n = -m}^\infty c_n e^{2i  \pi n \tau}$ i.e. $1/f$ is meromorphic at the cusp.

There is not much more to say, except that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n = -m}^\infty c_n q^n$ is the absolute value of the first zeros of $g(q)$, that in general is not $1$, for example take $f(\tau) = G_{2k}(\tau), k \ge 6$ an Eisenstein series [having some zeros on $\mathbb{H}$](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~nbruin/pnwntc2010/slides/treneer.pdf).

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much for that explicit solution. When I just read it in a sentence of a book. I thought it's going to be a kind of trivial thing. But it Seems to be not that trivial

Comment: What does that $f(\tau) ~e^{2i \pi m\tau} $ mean?

Comment: @Deavor  Nothing really complicated. I just wanted to make the Fourier expansion rigorous by going to the unit disk / function of $q$. And you are asking $f(\tau) \sim e^{2i \pi m \tau}$ ? It is the growth rate of $f$ as $\tau \to i \infty$, equivalently since $f(\tau) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{2i\pi n \tau}$ it means $a_n = 0$ for $n < m$

Comment: @Deavor you don't know the usual Fourier series ?