# Eisenstein series, exact sequence map and Modular Forms as a Direct Sum of Cusp Forms and Eisenstein series

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

We have the map $0\to S_k\to M_k\to C$, where $S_k$ is the subspace of weight $k$ cusp forms and $M_k$ is the space of modular forms.
It is clear the map from $S_k$ to $M_k$ is injective as this is just inclusion. But for the map $M_k\to C$, we are sending $f(z)\rightarrow f(\infty)$. The kernel is clearly the cusp forms and we have the Eisenstein series $G_k$ going to $2\zeta(k)$.  But how do we get from this that the map is surjective?

Also, from here, Serre in *A Course in Arithmetic* concludes that $M_k=S_k \bigoplus\mathbb CG_k$.  Am I missing something here? Is there some theorem that says whenever we have an exact sequence, the thing in the middle is a direct sum of the thing on the left and a product of the thing on the right and something else (in this case, the something else is the Eisenstein series).

Comment: It is obvious that $M_k = S_k \bigoplus \mathbb{C}G_k$. Take $f \in M_k$ and look at $h(z) = f(z)-f(i\infty)\frac{G_k(z)}{G_k(i\infty)}$ clearly $h \in S_k$

Comment: Also [take a look at this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1960141/if-f-is-a-meromorphic-modular-form-of-weight-k-then-frac1f-is-a-modu/1960205#1960205) the definition of "$f \in M_k$ is a modular form for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$" is made such that $g(q) = f(\frac{\log(q)}{2i\pi})$ is meromorphic on the unit disk and holomorphic at $q= 0$, with a zero at $q= 0$ iff it is a cusp form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c\in\mathbb{C}$ and $E_k$ is the normalized Eisenstein series of weight $k$, then the function
\begin{equation}
f = c E_K
\end{equation}
is a modular form of weight $k$ whose Fourier expansion starts with $c$, so it is mapped to $f(\infty)=c$ as required. This shows surjectivity of the map $\mathcal{M}_k \to \mathbb{C}$ hence the sequence you have written is exact.

In general, it is not true that if we have an exact sequence then the middle term is isomorphic to the direct sum of the outer two: when this happens the sequence is called *split*. However, the involved objects are all finite dimensional complex vector spaces, and in this case we can conclude that $\mathcal{M}_k = \mathcal{S}_k \oplus \mathbb{C}E_k$. This is a general fact about vector spaces that can be proved by hand or deduced from more general considerations: every finite dimensional vector space is free, hence every exact sequence of finite dimensional vector spaces is split.